# parsley.js with AngularJS for form validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, parsley.js

I'm developing application using AngularJS (using requireJS). I want to validate input fields (basically all client side validation). I thought to use Parsley.js which looks great but it doesn't work with AngularJS. HTML5 validation overrides parsley validation.

So my questions are
1) Any idea why parsley is not working with my angular app? 
2) Which is best validator for angular (except angular default validation)?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into this as well. Seems that someone on SO has created a directive to make Parsley work with Angular. [Click.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934222/parsley-validation-not-working-angular-js)

The best validator, as of yet, to me seems to be the built-in Angular validation. Though multi-field validation is still a pickle.

Comment: Hi Dormouse, Thanks for the answer. As of now I'm using Angular Validator. Which serves my purpose, but was really wondering why we cannot use parsley directly. In the SO some have created directive in coffeescript (which I dont know :)). But thanks for your answer anyway..!

Comment: @Sammi I am curious - what did you end up doing?  I am currently looking into this as well.

Comment: @RyanAlberts I started using Angular-Validator which is from Angular team, simple and easy  :). https://github.com/kelp404/angular-validator

Comment: Personally I was leaning more towards [angular 1.3 form validation](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html).

Comment: Thanks @Sammi and Dormouse - I ended up going with angular 1.4.x validation route and ngMessage.  I did get Parsley 2.x working with Angular 1.3+ if you are interested - I can paste the code here.

Comment: Here was my solution in case it's helpful... http://ryanalberts.com/797/parsley-validation-with-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form role="form"
      ng-submit="submit(this.form, reg)"
      novalidate="novalidate" ...
```

to prevent native browser validation